# How to mock static map when testing httpServlet Filter using mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, static, mocking, mockito

I have the following:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "SessionFilter", urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class SessionFilter implements Filter {

    protected static  String timeAttribute = "time";
    protected static Map<String, myStats> urlToTimeCounterMapping = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); //Thread safe
```

When I use `doFilter`, I add an object to the map. So when testing my class, I expect `urlToTimeCounterMapping` size to be `1`. The problem is that it's static and I get `null`. Is there a way I can do it?

This is my test:

```
@Test
public void testDoFilter() throws Exception {
    // create the objects to be mocked
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
    FilterChain filterChain = mock(FilterChain.class);

    // mock the getRequestURI() response
    SessionFilter Rlla = new SessionFilter();
    Object aa = new Date();

    when(httpServletRequest.getAttribute("time")).thenReturn(aa);

    Rlla.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse, filterChain);

    boolean a = false;
    if (Rlla.urlToTimeCounterMapping.size() == 1) {
        a = true;
    }

    assertEquals(true, a);
}
```

editing:

The `doFilter` checks if it's a new url, if so - it will add it to the map with counter++, otherwise -it will update the counter for the existing url

Comment: Where is the code of doFilter()? What is the actual size of the map? Why is the map static in the first place?

Comment: It is static as I can't pass it to doFilter and it is counting the number of urls that were passed (so I can't initialize it each time..).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a mock, just set the Map to whatever values it needs to have in the setup. Using a mock in this instance is just overkill.

Comment: what do you mean? I tried using "when" and "theReturn" but I get an error